# Spring Boot GraphQL Schema Inspection: Unmapped Fields

Tags: spring, graphql, boot

I am running a Spring Boot application which is using a GraphQL API.  On startup, the GraphQL Schema Inspection shows multiple classes with unmapped fields:

```bash
2024-01-18T20:48:48.900Z  INFO 66 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.g.GraphQlAutoConfiguration       : GraphQL schema inspection:
surgio-api     |    Unmapped fields: {Query=[assets, assetTypes], Asset=[isTemplate], User=[isTwoFactorAuthEnabled, isAccountLocked, isPasswordExpired, isVerified], KeyPair=[isActive], AccountProperty=[isCustomerFacing]}
surgio-api     |    Unmapped registrations: {}
surgio-api     |    Skipped types: []
```

They all appear to be related to boolean fields I have on those classes.  I have followed the same standard for all of those classes for boolean fields, but here is one example using the `Asset.java` class:

```java
@Entity
public class Asset extends SoftDeleteEntity {
//----------------------------------------
// Member Variables
//----------------------------------------

    /**
     * Single Values
     */

    private boolean isTemplate;

//----------------------------------------
// Getter Methods
//----------------------------------------

    /**
     * Returns a flag indicating whether this asset can be used as a template for another asset
     *
     * @return the is asset template flag
     */
    public boolean isTemplate() {
        return this.isTemplate;
    }

//----------------------------------------
// Setter Methods
//----------------------------------------

    /**
     * Sets whether this asset can be used for another template
     *
     * @param isTemplate the is template flag
     */
    public void setTemplate(boolean isTemplate) {
        this.isTemplate = isTemplate;
    }
}
```

And here is the GraphQL scheme definition for that class:

```
type Asset {
    id: Int
    isTemplate: Boolean
}
```

The strange part is that it is mapping correctly and does return the correct value in the response.

What is the correct way of handling these?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a comparable error recently, but managed to address it by excluding ResponseEntity<> from the methods where I applied @QueryMapping in the controller class. All the controller methods were originally returning ResponseEntity. This approach resolved the issue for me, and I hope it proves helpful for you as well.

Comment: Strangely enough today my app is not complaining about it at all...and I've changed nothing.  Love those types of non-repeatable issues.